# git hub - forking a repo to a new branch

Tags: git, github

I forked a repo (an assignment), worked on it and completed it, then pushed up to  my fork.

How can I create a "practice" branch in my fork where I can re-fork the original repo and start from a blank slate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two different things that you could do:

1. Clone the original repo again and make a new "practice" repo.
2. Find the commit in your repo finished repo, corresponding to when you originally cloned it (or shortly after?), use `git checkout` to move the HEAD to there, then make a branch there using e.g. `git checkout -b practice`. Then you will have a practice branch.

Comment: thanks, I went with #2. So what I did was looked at the log, then these commands: git co [log #] / git co -b practice.  so now i'm on that branch. how do I ensure that I have all the respective/relevant files on my local system?

Comment: Well you'll have exactly the files that were checked in at whatever commit you were at, and you can be sure that your head is clean by typing `git status`. (It will tell you if there were modifications.)

Comment: ah you're right, and what I was looking for was there anyways. thanks!